# LeafletSlider plugin doesn't work

Tags: leaflet, data, time, timeslider

I downloaded the LeafletSlider repo https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider to test it out and then modify it to my needs, but when I open the index.html it doesn't have the slider as shown in the demo and the points in points.json aren't showing either.

Comment: Ayougo, are you using the example in the `LeafletSlider/examples/epoch.html` folder of the repo? Or are you having problems with your own code?

Comment: For now i'm just using the the example in the LeafletSlider/examples/epoch.html folder and the example in LeafletSlider/index.html both don't show the slider in the top right nor the markers. I tried to make my own code but it doesn't work either so I'm trying to locate the problem in the examples first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me - perhaps your computer is blocking some of the external dependencies (like jquery.com or leaflet.com).  Check the network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what may be failing.

Comment: I get this : jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/ayoub/Desktop/Leaflet/LeafletSlider-master/examples/epoch.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Instead of opening the file directly, you want to run a local development server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server